# How can I solve stack up problem in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using **webphnent** and when i click a link it calls functions.

but the problem is when i call each a link, it stack up every each div of `pie_arrests`

I need to replace them not stack up

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callChart(50035); callPie(50035); callMap(50035); callTitle('살인');">살인</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callChart(50047); callPie(50047); callMap(50047); callTitle('절도');">절도</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="chart_pie">
    <span class="div_sub1">검거자</span>
    <div class="pie_arrests"></div>
</div>
```

this is one of function!

```
function callChart(num) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.crimestats.or.kr/openapi/Sttsapitbldata.do?KEY=[...]&STATBL_ID=[...]&DTACYCLE_CD=YY&WRTTIME_IDTFR_ID=2016&Type=json&CLS_ID='+num,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {
            var  pie = webponent.visual.pie.init($(".pie_arrests"));
        }
   });
```

Comment: It's stupid to say, but try adding `$(".pie_arrests").html("");` as first row of *success*

Comment: @CristianTraìna thanks!!